# "Not a bootable partition" from Haiku's boot manager for new Linux partitions

Tags: centos, grub, multi-boot, boot-manager, haiku

I just did this:

1. made an Intel Extended partition covering the whole HD using Haiku Alpha 4.1's DriveSetup
2. made several BeOS partitions
3. deleted the first one
4. installed Haiku onto one of the other ones
5. installed CentOS 6.4 i386 into the empty space, which created two partitions within the empty space, the first being 500 MB
6. ran BootManager from Haiku and set up the menu to be able to boot to any partition

Now, when I boot, if I select Haiku, it boots fine.  If I select either of the CentOS partitions, it says, "Not a bootable partition".

Did CentOS forget to install GRUB or something?  Is this an issue with my CentOS setup, Haiku's BootManager, or with my use of Extended Intel partitions?

FWIW, I used to run PC-BSD, and IIRC Peppermint Linux also, on here using the same methodology--except for the Extended Intel part, because I only needed four partitions--and they would boot from Haiku's BootManager just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it didn't install GRUB, probably to avoid trashing an existing bootloader since I wasn't using the whole drive.

To fix it, I booted into the install medium again (minimal, prepared using ISO2USB), chose the rescue option from the initial menu, went through until I got a command prompt, then:

```
chroot /mnt/sysimage/
cat /boot/grub/grub.conf
```

Then seeing it's installed at (hd0,8) in grub notation, did this:

```
grub-install hd0,8
```

Now it boots (from the 500MB partition, but not the other one) when I select it in Haiku's BootManager.